# Multilinear regression

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model

The following code fits multi-linear regression model and produces coefficients that I don't quite know where they come from.

```
n <- 10000         # use large sample size to get precise estimates
x1 <- rnorm(n, 0, 1) #generated 10000 random numbers, mean =0, sd =1
x2 <- x1 + rnorm(n, 0, 0.1) #error random numbers, mean =0, sd =0.1
y <- 2 * x1 - x2 + rnorm(n, 0, 1)
x3 <- y + rnorm(n, 0, 1)

# Fit different regression models:
coef(lm(y ~ x1))           # beta1=1 
coef(lm(y ~ x2))           # beta2=1 
coef(lm(y ~ x3))           # beta3=2/3
coef(lm(y ~ x1 + x2))      # beta1=2, beta2=-1
coef(lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3)) # beta1=1, beta2=-1/2, beta3=1/2
```

The beta3 is 2/3, why is that? Can someone explicitly show me the calculation process?

The purpose of this exercise is to illustrate that $\beta_k$ is the "effect" of $x_k$ on Y when all other variables in the model are held constant. This "effect" should *not* be interpreted as a causal effect. When comparing two observations i and j, where $x_{ik} = x_{jk} + 1$ (i.e., values for $x_k$ differ by one) and $x_{ir} = x_{jr}$ for all other $r$ in $\{1,..,p\}$ (i.e., values for all other variables $x_r$ are identical), then $E(Y_i) = E(Y_j) + \beta_k$.

I do understand the purpose of this example perfectly, I just wonder what calculation is behind the 2/3 value

Comment: This is a nice exercise! Thanks for sharing with us.
For me to understand (or at least to belief to understand) the beta3 = 2/3, it helps to think of 2x1  x2 = x1 (approximately). So y consists of 2 random compoments: x1 + rnorm(n, 0, 1). x3 consists of 3 random components, with 2 beeing the same like y.

Comment: Do you mean, why is beta3 2/3 rather than some other value?

Comment: @TinglTanglBob i don't know if I understood you correctly. But your explanation seems not depending on the variance. However, when I change the sd of rnorm to 0.1, the coefficient changes accordingly

Comment: @mdewey I mean from what algebraic calculation 2/3 comes from, because it looks to me that the number is quite simple is straight forward intuitively.

Comment: @datings: I think this is because each component in the current setup adds the same amount of variance. If you set all the sd of the rnorm-commands (expect the 0.1 for x2) to 2 beta3 is 0.66 as well. Maybe this is just a lucky coincident and my guess is totally wrong :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine the data are plotted with $y$ at y-axis and $x3$ at x-axis. The rnorm() term in "x3 <- y + rnorm(n, 0, 1)" smears the data point horizontally to the left and right.

Recalling that the slope, $\beta_1$, is computed by:

$$\beta_1 = \frac{\Sigma(x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y})}{\Sigma(x_i - \bar{x})^2}$$

Holding $y_i$ unchanged, the more extreme the individual point, $x_i$, spread out, the denominator would increase faster than the numerator would, hence as you dial up the SD of in the "rnorm()", the beta moves closer to 0. For instance, try "rnorm(n, 0, 0.1)" and "rnorm(n, 0, 10)" and check it yourself.

---

> Or more explicitly, why is it 2 in the numerator and 3 in the
>   denominator?

Top part can be perceived as a function of the covariance of $y$ and $x3$ (sans the divide by (n-1) part but the ratio is not changing here), and the denominator can be perceived as the variance of $x3$ alone. Try:

```
n <- 10000      
x1 <- rnorm(n, 0, 1)
x2 <- x1 + rnorm(n, 0, 0.1) 
y <- 2 * x1 - x2 + rnorm(n, 0, 1)
x3 <- y + rnorm(n, 0, 1)

cov(x3,y)
var(x3)
```

Then you should see:

```
> cov(x3,y)
[1] 1.964835
> var(x3)
[1] 2.966569
```

Which is roughly 2/3.

Comment: (+1) That is all true, but can you spell out for the OP why that leads to 2/3 for the particular variance in the example?

Comment: Thank you, your answer does make sense qualitatively. I fail to see the quantitative connection though, namely why is 2/3 equal to your stated formula? Or more explicitly, why is it 2 in the numerator and 3 in the denominator?

Comment: @dantings, please see my edits in the answer.

Comment: (+1) If my calculations are correct, the exact value of the coefficient should be $201/301$.